# JSON Parsing with Robotframework-httplibrary.HTTP

Tags: json, robotframework

I have a json data like below :

```
{  
   "val1":"1",
   "val2":"",
   "val3":"test123",
   "mode":"test",
   "items":[  
      {  
         "item":{  
            "id":"234",
            "idvalue":"",
            "item2":"ordertest",
            "action":"Add",
            "productOffering":{  
               "id":"PO_I"
            },
            "product":{  
               "productId":"pid"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to get the value for "item2" i.e. - ordertest. I tried the below code:

```
${A}  |  Get Json Value   |   ${JSON_File}    |   /items/item/item2
Log   | ${A}
```

but getting an error :

`- FAIL : JsonPointerException: 'item' is not a valid list index`

Please help Regards

Comment: did my answer solve the problem @navin?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON access is the problem, remember you have an array in there, try this:

```
${A}  |  Get Json Value   |   ${JSON_File}    |      /items/0/item/item2
```